# Int getting converted to double while trying to save to the db

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to save a simple form but the int value is getting turned into a double. Example: I enter the value 87, click Save, and the value gets turned into 87,00.

[image: error message]

"" must be a number between - and +.

My jsf code for this input:

```
<t:inputNumber label="hr.label.LeaveDay" value="#{employeeLeaveHome.entity.leaveDay}" columnClass="col-xs-6" required="true"/>
```

I need it so it stays as the value I've put in. Ex: 87. I don't know why it's showing this behavior. It's defined as an int in the model.

Comment: The table column or entity field type should not be affected by what happens in the UI.  Where are you seeing `87,00` and why is this a problem for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default is to display two decimal places. Either configure it differently or do:

```
<t:inputNumber label="hr.label.LeaveDay" value="#{employeeLeaveHome.entity.leaveDay}"
    decimalPlaces="0"/>
```

So it is a displaying issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!